# If $R_1$ and $R_2$ are symmetric and transitive, prove that also $R_1 \cup R_2$ is symmetric and transitive

Tags: proof-writing, relations, symmetry

I have to prove or confute (with a counter example) that, if $R_1$ and $R_2$ are symmetric and transitive, then $R_1 \cup R_2$ is also symmetric and transitive.

---

**Note**: *To prove the transitive case, I think I will ask a separate question, so that we can focus on the symmetric part now.*

---

The first thing I thought to do was to think about what does it mean $R_1$ and $R_2$ to be symmetric and transitive. Then I conclude that if a pair $(x, y) \in R_1$, then also $(y, x) \in R_1$.

I assumed also that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are define on a set $A = \{x, y, z \}$

I have to keep in my what is my goal: **prove that $R_1 \cup R_2$ is symmetric**, which means that if $((x, y) \in R_1 \cup R_2) \rightarrow ((y, x) \in R_1 \cup R_2)$. At this point, I could try to assume $(x, y) \in R_1 \cup R_2$ and prove $(y, x) \in R_1 \cup R_2$:

Assuming $(x, y) \in R_1 \cup R_2$, which means $(x, y) \in R_1 \lor (x, y) \in R_2$, I have to split my proof in 2 cases:

1. **Case 1**: I assume $(x, y) \in R_1$

   Since $R_1$ is symmetric, then $(y, x) \in R_1$. Since we know now that $(y, x) \in R_1$, we can say that $(y, x) \in R_1 \cup R_2$
2. **Case 2**: I assume $(x, y) \in R_2$

   Since $R_2$ is symmetric, then $(y, x) \in R_2$. Since we know now that $(y, x) \in R_2$, we can say that $(y, x) \in R_1 \cup R_2$

Is this a proof of the fact that, if $R_1$ and $R_2$ is symmetric, then also $R_1 \cup R_2$ is?

Comment: What do you know about the relationship between the sets $A$ and $A\cup B$, which is contained in which? Once you know that, you're almost done. In case 1, by hypothesis, what should happen once $(x,y)\in R_1$?, Is $R_1$ symmetric?, what does that imply?

Comment: It is correct indeed. Are you sure why, in these types of proofs, you have to split it into two cases?

Comment: Yes, you know $\alpha \lor \beta$ is true once one of them is true.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20183/discussion-between-miguelgondu-and-rinzler).

Answer (score 0):

You might try this with a few examples of $R_1$ and $R_2$.  For instance, consider the set of all line segments in the plane.  If $A$ and $B$ are two line segments, let $A\mathrel{R_1}B$ if $A$ and $B$ have the same length, and $A \mathrel{R_2} B$ if $A$ and $B$ have the same slope (or are both vertical).  Clearly $R_1$ and $R_2$ are symmetric and transitive (indeed, they are both equivalence relations).  $R_1 \cup R_2$ is the relation that $A$ and $B$ have *either* the same length *or* the same slope (or both).

The conditions you need to check are:

- *symmetry*: If $A$ and $B$ have the same length or the same slope, do $B$ and $A$ have the same length or slope?
- *transitivity*: If $A$ and $B$ have the same length or the same slope, and $B$ and $C$ have the same length or the same slope, must $A$ and $C$ have the same length or the same slope?  Draw some pictures and I think you might see the issue.

Symmetry looks pretty straightforward.  IF $A$ has the same length as $B$ or $A$ is parallel to $B$, one of those has to be true.  If $A$ has the same length as $B$, then $B$ has the same length as $A$.  Or, if $A$ is parallel to $B$, then $B$ is parallel to $A$.  In either case, the statement “$B$ has the same length as $A$ or $B$ is parallel to $A$” is true.

On the other hand...what if $A$ has the same length as $B$, but $B$ is parallel to $C$?  Is it necessarily true that $A$ has the same length as $C$, or is parallel to $C$?  It's not to hard to come up with a counterexample.  For instance, $A$ and $B$ can be perpendicular but have the same length, and $C$ parallel to $B$ but twice as long.

This example ought to convince you that if $R_1$ and $R_2$ are symmetric, then $R_1 \cup R_2$ must be symmetric.  However, if $R_1$ and $R_2$ are transitive, $R_1 \cup R_2$ need not be transitive.